# How do I override a panel pane admin title?

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

I am trying to provide an overview to my site's admins of what each panel pane is exactly doing by trying to provide extra information in views panes, as I have panel pages with many regions and panes. For instance, rather than saying 'View: {View name} : {Display name} it would be a lot more helpful if I could label each of those differently, by adding custom text, views arguments dynamically, etc. I have tried a number of hooks like hook_panels_pane_prerender, but they only affect the front end, not the panel page on admin. How could I achieve this?